# How to install command line tools without error that is not currently available on Software Update server?

Tags: macos, xcode, command-line

I am using maverick, and have Xcode 5.0.2.

I am trying to install command line tools using `xcode-select --install`, but I get message that is not currently available on Software Update server.

What may be wrong?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19907576/xcode-is-not-currently-available-from-the-software-update-server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have an Apple Developer Account, then visit [this](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=command) Site.
 If you don't have an account, you can register one with the link I provided too.
After that you can download the package from the before mentioned link.

Comment: Ok, somehow I was not properly registered...