# "xcode-select --install" versus retrieving the dmg from Apple's developer website

Tags: terminal, macos, xcode, command-line

I would to ask a question closely related to already existing posts ([How to install command line tools without error that is not currently available on Software Update server?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/112804/how-to-install-command-line-tools-without-error-that-is-not-currently-availabl) and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19691701/failed-to-install-command-line-tools-on-osx-mavericks) but with the help of which I still could not fully solve my problem.

I have a MacBook Pro running Mac OSX 10.9. When I run `xcode-select --install`  from the terminal, the command fails with an error message `Can't install software because it is not currently available from the Software Update Server` (see second linked post for screenshot).

It was suggested by many to simply download the command line tools package from the developer website, which I have done (already had an account). My question, is the second procedure strictly equivalent to running `xcode-select --install`? I have suspicions that the paths to the different libraries and headers are not defined in the same way when downloading and executing the dmg.

I am running particle physics software called root and compiling with the available C++ interpreter fails with "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64" error, probably due to the use of standard libc++ instead of libstdc++. Strangely enough this problem does not appear on another computer (running same OSX 10.9) where I was able to run the `xcode-select --install` command.

Is there any way to solve this error message when running `xcode-select --install`? People have suggested this could be due to the fact that command line tools are already installed but I have both tried deleting command line tools by hand (`sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`) and even a clean install of Mavericks but no luck.

Comment: That error "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64"  is not due to libc++ It is because you have some libraries in 32 bit only and the main is in 64 bit (or in both)  - this is one reason I use package managers like macports/fink/homebrew as the porters will tell you if it can't be fixed . root is a very complex build

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure they are installing the same version?

At the command line on both machines run `cc -v` - the latest version seems to be `Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)`.

Comment: Hi, yes I have already checked versions on both machines and they are the same, namely the one you mention in your post. This is why I suspect some different flag setting somewhere and would like to try the xcode-select --install method to make sure. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -2):

Also, try running

```
export
```

to see what environment variables you have set; it's likely that the development tools are prefixed somewhere you don't have a path, so the shell can't find them.